# Ошибка Cannot create property 'scope' on string

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Использую vee-validate, имеется код, не могу понять, почему не отрабатывает как надо.
(должен проверять, зарегистрирован ли телефон или нет, если да - выводить ошибку)

template:

```
<div class='form-group' :class='{"form-group_invalid": errors.has("phone_number")}'>
 <input
  v-validate='"required"'
  name='phone_number'
  type='text'
  placeholder='Mobile phone'
  v-model='user.phoneNumber'
  autocomplete='tel'
/>


<div class='form-group__error' v-if='!takenPhoneNumber'>
 {{ errors.first('phone_number')}}</div>

<div class='form-group__error' v-if='takenPhoneNumber'>
 <span>Ошибка</span>
</div>
```

Кусочек кода из вью, отвечающий на получение и изменение состояния `takenPhoneNumber`:

```
  data() {
   return {
   takenPhoneNumber: false,
   };
  },
  methods: {
   .catch(({ response }) => {
     if (response && response.data) {
      const errors = response.data.errors;
      this.takenPhoneNumber = response.data.takenPhoneNumber;
      this.errors.clear();

      for (const field of Object.keys(errors)) {
       this.errors.add(field, errors[field]);
      }
     }
    }
```

В вьютулс состояние `takenPhoneNumber` меняется корректно (прилетает true, если такой телефон есть).
Но не выводится в форме, появляется ошибка в консоли:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что нужно добавь/изменить?

Answer (score 1):

422 статус, это ругается валидатор Laravel c бэкэнда,вариантов несколько, 1 вы не шлете в запросе к бэку CSRF токен, либо шлете не те данные в переменной phone_number, валидатор ждет строку, не массив, не обьект а именно строку

Comment: Да, думаю, проблема в последнем (про строку), теперь надо понять как ему правильно отправить)

Comment: const num = 123; 
const str = num.toString(); 
 как то так можно, ну или перед отправкой в консоль выведите данные и посмотрите, что шлет